# Huobi working python 3.6 example create url (including signature)

Tags: python-3.x, api, signing

Working example to generate a valid url (including signature) for the Huobi API.

In the Huobi API documenation there is no explicit example that allows you to verify your signature creation method step by step.

My intention is to create that here, but I need help, because I haven't managed yet.

The following is supposed to be the recipe.

Note that once you have this working, substitute valid values for your API key + secret and timestamp:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

from urllib.parse import urlencode

API_KEY = 'dummy-key'
API_SECRET = 'dummy-secret'
timestamp = '2021-03-04T11:36:39'

params_dict = {
    'AccessKeyId': API_KEY,
    'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
    'SignatureVersion': '2',
    'Timestamp': timestamp
}
params_url_enc = urlencode(sorted(params_dict.items()))

pre_signed = 'GET\n'
pre_signed += 'api.huobi.pro\n'
pre_signed += '/v1/account/accounts\n'
pre_signed += params_url_enc

sig_bytes = hmac.new(
    API_SECRET.encode(),
    pre_signed.encode(),
    hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().encode()
sig_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sig_bytes)
sig_b64_str = sig_b64_bytes.decode()
sig_url = urlencode({'Signature': sig_b64_str})

url = 'https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?'
url += params_url_enc + '&'
url += sig_url

print('API_KEY={}'.format(API_KEY))
print('API_SECRET={}'.format(API_SECRET))
print('timestamp={}'.format(timestamp))
print('params_dict={}'.format(params_dict))
print('params_url_enc={}'.format(params_url_enc))
print('pre_signed:\n{}'.format(pre_signed))
print('sig_bytes={}'.format(sig_bytes))
print('sig_b64_bytes={}'.format(sig_b64_bytes))
print('sig_b64_str={}'.format(sig_b64_str))
print('sig_url={}'.format(sig_url))
print('url={}'.format(url))
```

Gives:

```
API_KEY=dummy-key
API_SECRET=dummy-secret
timestamp=2021-03-04T11:36:39
params_dict={'AccessKeyId': 'dummy-key', 'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256', 'SignatureVersion': '2', 'Timestamp': '2021-03-04T11:36:39'}
params_url_enc=AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T11%3A36%3A39
pre_signed:
GET
api.huobi.pro
/v1/account/accounts
AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T11%3A36%3A39
sig_bytes=b'1921de9f42284bc0449c5580f52a9f7e7e3a54a6e8befc0d320992e757517a6b'
sig_b64_bytes=b'MTkyMWRlOWY0MjI4NGJjMDQ0OWM1NTgwZjUyYTlmN2U3ZTNhNTRhNmU4YmVmYzBkMzIwOTkyZTc1NzUxN2E2Yg=='
sig_b64_str=MTkyMWRlOWY0MjI4NGJjMDQ0OWM1NTgwZjUyYTlmN2U3ZTNhNTRhNmU4YmVmYzBkMzIwOTkyZTc1NzUxN2E2Yg==
sig_url=Signature=MTkyMWRlOWY0MjI4NGJjMDQ0OWM1NTgwZjUyYTlmN2U3ZTNhNTRhNmU4YmVmYzBkMzIwOTkyZTc1NzUxN2E2Yg%3D%3D
url=https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T11%3A36%3A39&Signature=MTkyMWRlOWY0MjI4NGJjMDQ0OWM1NTgwZjUyYTlmN2U3ZTNhNTRhNmU4YmVmYzBkMzIwOTkyZTc1NzUxN2E2Yg%3D%3D
```

Also add header in sending:

```
{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

Unfortunately, when I substitute my own valid API key + secret and a proper UTC time stamp, I invariably receive:

```
{"status":"error","err-code":"api-signature-not-valid","err-msg":"Signature not valid: Verification failure [校验失败]","data":null}
```

So what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was that I took the hexidigest of the hash, whereas the digest was needed.

**Working recipe here** that you can check numerically to validate your code:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

from urllib.parse import urlencode

API_KEY = 'dummy-key'
API_SECRET = 'dummy-secret'
timestamp = '2021-03-04T12:54:56'

params_dict = {
    'AccessKeyId': API_KEY,
    'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
    'SignatureVersion': '2',
    'Timestamp': timestamp
}
params_url_enc = urlencode(
    sorted(params_dict.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[0]))

pre_signed = 'GET\n'
pre_signed += 'api.huobi.pro\n'
pre_signed += '/v1/account/accounts\n'
pre_signed += params_url_enc

sig_bin = hmac.new(
    API_SECRET.encode(),
    pre_signed.encode(),
    hashlib.sha256).digest()
sig_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sig_bin)
sig_b64_str = sig_b64_bytes.decode()
sig_url = urlencode({'Signature': sig_b64_str})

url = 'https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?'
url += params_url_enc + '&'
url += sig_url

print('API_KEY={}'.format(API_KEY))
print('API_SECRET={}'.format(API_SECRET))
print('timestamp={}'.format(timestamp))
print('params_dict={}'.format(params_dict))
print('params_url_enc={}'.format(params_url_enc))
print('pre_signed:\n{}'.format(pre_signed))
print('sig_bin={}'.format(sig_bin))
print('sig_b64_bytes={}'.format(sig_b64_bytes))
print('sig_b64_str={}'.format(sig_b64_str))
print('sig_url={}'.format(sig_url))
print('url={}'.format(url))
```

Result:

```
$ python test_huobi_so.py
API_KEY=dummy-key
API_SECRET=dummy-secret
timestamp=2021-03-04T12:54:56
params_dict={'AccessKeyId': 'dummy-key', 'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256', 'SignatureVersion': '2', 'Timestamp': '2021-03-04T12:54:56'}
params_url_enc=AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T12%3A54%3A56
pre_signed:
GET
api.huobi.pro
/v1/account/accounts
AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T12%3A54%3A56
sig_bin=b'_\xb9k\x82!\xb4B%A\xfe\x0c \xff\x07%JE\xbe\x82\x8b-<^\xb7\xfc\x06\x85G\xb5$\x81\xd7'
sig_b64_bytes=b'X7lrgiG0QiVB/gwg/wclSkW+gostPF63/AaFR7Ukgdc='
sig_b64_str=X7lrgiG0QiVB/gwg/wclSkW+gostPF63/AaFR7Ukgdc=
sig_url=Signature=X7lrgiG0QiVB%2Fgwg%2FwclSkW%2BgostPF63%2FAaFR7Ukgdc%3D
url=https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?AccessKeyId=dummy-key&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-03-04T12%3A54%3A56&Signature=X7lrgiG0QiVB%2Fgwg%2FwclSkW%2BgostPF63%2FAaFR7Ukgdc%3D
```

Answer (score 1):

Huobi API documentation is
https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#introduction

To get all accounts, use endpoint GET /v1/account/accounts

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode

#Get all Accounts of the Current User
AccessKeyId = 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'
SecretKey = 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'
timestamp = str(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())[0:19]
params = urlencode({'AccessKeyId': AccessKeyId,
                    'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
                    'SignatureVersion': '2',
                    'Timestamp': timestamp
                   })
method = 'GET'
endpoint = '/v1/account/accounts'
base_uri = 'api.huobi.pro'
pre_signed_text = method + '\n' + base_uri + '\n' + endpoint + '\n' + params
hash_code = hmac.new(SecretKey.encode(), pre_signed_text.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = urlencode({'Signature': base64.b64encode(hash_code).decode()})
url = 'https://' + base_uri + endpoint + '?' + params + '&' + signature
response = requests.request(method, url)
accts = json.loads(response.text)
print(accts)
```

Subsequently, if you need to run another endpoint (note timestamp allowance is ±5 minutes),

example, to get account balance, use GET `/v1/account/accounts/{account_id}/balance`

```
#Get Account Balance of a Specific Account
account_id = accts['data'][0]['id']
method = 'GET'
endpoint = '/v1/account/accounts/{}/balance'.format(account_id)
pre_signed_text = method + '\n' + base_uri + '\n' + endpoint + '\n' + params
hash_code = hmac.new(SecretKey.encode(), pre_signed_text.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = urlencode({'Signature': base64.b64encode(hash_code).decode()})
url = 'https://' + base_uri + endpoint + '?' + params + '&' + signature
response = requests.request(method, url)
r = json.loads(response.text)
print(r)
```

Comment: very nice. how Do i add request parameters? For example in the endpoint 
`endpoint = '/linear-swap-api/v1/swap_balance_valuation?valuation_asset=BTC'`

results in error 403, incorrect access key

Comment: the request parameters should be in the endpoint (like what you did above), then use it to get the `pre_signed_text`, then the rest remains unchanged